# Segmentation fault (core dumped) using stringstream

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, stringstream

I ran into this issue when trying to switch from printing to the command line with cout to making it a string using stringstream and streamstring.str(). My code is as follows:

```
string Similarity::maxJaccard(){
    double currentJaccardValue(0.0);
    double maxJaccardValue(0.0);
    int index1(0);
    int index2(0);
    double jaccardNumerator(0.0);
    double jaccardDenominator(0.0);
    stringstream ss;

    vector<int> compareToVector;
    vector<int> compareAgainstVector;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < containingVector.size(); i++){
            compareToVector = containingVector.at(i);
            index1 = i;
            jaccardDenominator = compareToVector.size();
            for(unsigned int j = 0; j < containingVector.size(); j++){
                    jaccardNumerator = 0.0;
                    if(i != j){
                            compareAgainstVector = containingVector.at(j);
                            index2 = j;
                            for(unsigned int k = 0; k < compareToVector.size(); k++){
                                    if(compareToVector.at(k) == compareAgainstVector.at(k)){
                                            jaccardNumerator = jaccardNumerator + 1.0;
                                    }
                            }
                            currentJaccardValue = jaccardNumerator/jaccardDenominator;
                            if(currentJaccardValue >= maxJaccardValue){
                                    maxJaccardValue = currentJaccardValue;
                                    if(index1 < 10){
                                            ss << "New Maximum at: " << index1 << "  " << index2 << " " << printVector(compareToVector) << " " << printVector(compareAgainstVector) << " " << currentJaccardValue << "\n";

                                    }else if(index2 < 10){
                                            ss << "New Maximum at: " << index1 << " " << index2 << "  " << printVector(compareToVector) << " " << printVector(compareAgainstVector) << " " << currentJaccardValue << "\n";

                                    }else{
                                            ss << "New Maximum at: " << index1 << " " << index2 << " " << printVector(compareToVector) << " " << printVector(compareAgainstVector) << " " << currentJaccardValue << "\n";
                                    }
                            }
                    }else{
                    }
            }
    }
    string s = ss.str();
    return s;
 }
```

printVector is a simple for loop running over the items in each vector and returning them as a string. Returns a string.

```
 string Similarity::printVector(vector<int> vector){
    ostringstream ss;
    string s = "( ";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
            ss << (vector.at(i));
            ss << " ";
    } s+= ss.str();
    s+= ")";
    return s;
 }
```

When I compile and run, I get a

```
 Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

When the code simply used cout, it ran perfectly fine. I'm not quite sure why using streamstring of cout would cause that.

Any and all help is appreciated,
Thanks in advance.

*EDIT: Edits made for clarity.

Comment: Use a debugger, step through it and see where it crashes.

Comment: What is the return type/value of printVector?

Comment: question edited for clarity, printVector added. printVector returns a string. currently stepping over the program in gdb. I'll post those results when I get them.